# Star-Lord and the Space Police

Tags: mathematics, geometry, pursuit-evasion

Star-Lord is on a deserted planet along with two space policemen. If he runs into either of them, he will get immediately arrested. Fortunately for Star-Lord, somewhere on two opposite ends of the planet he has hidden a jetpack and a battery for it, which are visible only to him.

Assuming all characters have the same speed, have full information about others' locations and can take decisions in real time, can the policemen prevent Star-Lord from getting his jetpack and its battery and flying away from the planet? What if there is only one policeman?

*Remark: The policemen are aware that Star-Lord has hidden his jetpack and its battery in two antipodal positions. However, their exact locations are unknown to them. The policemen can not see the items even if SL picks one them or they stand on top of the other.*

Comment: do you mean there are two jetpacks in antipodal position exactly 90º away from him?

Comment: There is just one jetpack and one battery for it, which are in antipodal positions. However, the position of Star-Lord with respect to them is known only to him.

Comment: and where are the two policemen relative to the meridian SL, the jetpack, and the battery form?

Comment: They are in arbitrary positions. Basically the question is can Star-Lord escape 1) always 2) sometimes 3) never.

Comment: Do the policemen know about the jetpack and battery, and their relative locations to each other?

Comment: Good question. The policemen know that the jetpack and the battery are in antipodal positions, even though do not know their exact locations. Will edit my post to add this information.

Comment: Well, if one of them is exactly where SL is, he would instantly get catched ;)

Comment: Haha, that's true, good start:)

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain, sorry for torturing you with my horrible English.

Comment: No torture at all; I'm just trying to make the question as clear as possible for future readers!  Thanks for posting!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's my answer:

> To guarantee SL will never reach one of his items, the policemen **need** to guarantee he'll stay in one hemisphere. For if he doesn't it's easy to give initial conditions with which he can get both of his items and escape.

Once this is settled, we can easily say the problem can be solved

> always.

The strategy being:

> While one of the policemen chases him, as in the famous [dog-rabbit problem](ftp://math.feld.cvut.cz/pub/tkadlec/papers/tdarcr.pdf), the other one must mirror his movements relative to the great circle perpendicular his and SL's initial positions. This way, you guarantee he'll never leave one hemisphere.

Bonus:

> With this, we see you need only one policemen to keep him at the planet.

Second Bonus FTW:

> In fact, the second policeman can catch SL. Once SL is trapped in an hemisphere, send the second policeman to the pole of the hemisphere (the furthest point from the great circle). After this, since their speeds are all equal, this policeman can **always** be in the same meridian as SL (meridians in this case are the great circles orthogonal to the equator) and, additionally, move towards him, since he moves through parallels faster than SL.

Comment: This sounds interesting... How do you keep SL in one hemisphere though? I'm pretty sure that if you have one policeman only, you can not do such thing.

Comment: **Spoiler:** Imagine you're SL and there's a policeman. Draw the great circle from which each point is equidistant from you and the policeman. If he mirrors your movements you'll never be able to cross said circle.

Comment: That's very good, I had another strategy in mind, but this is much simpler and works for one policeman as well. Great job!

Comment: I thought of a couple more complicated case-based strategies before arriving to this solution :)

Comment: See the second bonus, @ArturKirkoryan.

Comment: Yes, if we assume that SL and the policemen are physical entities (not dots), this strategy works for catching SL. If we assume they are dots, then their projector can end up an infinite spiral around the equator. Good job!

Comment: Exactly. ------

Comment: Because of the curvature of the planet, wouldn't the circle he can't eclipse be exactly a hemisphere, and thus if the jetpack was and battery were both on this, then he could in fact escape depending on the initial location of the 2nd police officer because he would have finite time to catch SL

Comment: @qwertylpc, he can't really touch the jetpack and the battery if they are on the great circle - in the moment he ends up on it, the space policeman would be also there and catch him. Basically he is restricted in an open hemisphere.

Comment: Oh ya I just realized that